# KeyError iterating through keys in a list

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

Hi all so I wrote a function which is something like this

```
def solve_one_shop(shop, items):
    if len(items) == 0:
        return [0.0, []]
    all_possible = []
    first_item = items[0]
    print shop['burger']
    for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:
        # DO SOMETHING
        #

solver(shop_text,['burger'])
```

The dictionary that Im trying to iterate over is this :

```
{'1': {'burger': [[4.0, ['burger']]], 'tofu_log': [[8.0, ['tofu_log']]]}, '3': {'chef_salad': [[4.0, ['chef_salad']]], 'steak_salad_sandwich': [[8.0, ['steak_salad_sandwich']]]}, '2': {'burger': [[5.0, ['burger']]], 'tofu_log': [[6.5, ['tofu_log']]]}, '5': {'extreme_fajita': [[4.0, ['extreme_fajita']]], 'fancy_european_water': [[8.0, ['fancy_european_water']]]}, '4': {'wine_spritzer': [[2.5, ['wine_spritzer']]], 'steak_salad_sandwich': [[5.0, ['steak_salad_sandwich']]]}, '6': {'extra_salsa': [[6.0, ['extreme_fajita', 'jalapeno_poppers', 'extra_salsa']]], 'jalapeno_poppers': [[6.0, ['extreme_fajita', 'jalapeno_poppers', 'extra_salsa']]], 'extreme_fajita': [[6.0, ['extreme_fajita', 'jalapeno_poppers', 'extra_salsa']]], 'fancy_european_water': [[5.0, ['fancy_european_water']]]}}
```

The problem is that the 6th line is giving KeyError ( shop[first_item] ).

```
[[4.0, ['burger']]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "working.py", line 58, in <module>
    solver(shop_text,['burger'])
  File "working.py", line 44, in solver
    (price, solution) = solve_one_shop(shop_info, required_items)
  File "working.py", line 29, in solve_one_shop
    for (price,combo) in shop.get(first_item):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

To overcome this error I tried hardcoding, so for example if I hardcode the first_item as `shop['burger']` **(along with single quotes)**, then the code runs.

But if I write it as `shop[burger]` , then it throws the same `KeyError: 'burger'`

As you can see , `print shop['burger']` outputs the availability of the key `'burger'`, but then why the KeyError.

How to fix this?

Comment: 1) I don't see a `KeyError`, I see a type error. 2) `burger` and `'burger'` are not at all the same thing. The former looks for a variable called `burger` to use its value as a key. The second is the string `'burger'`. 3) The `TypeError` suggests that `shop` was empty (`None`) instead of containing a `dict`

Answer (score 5):

If you want a safer way to access dictionary keys in python I would suggest using the `get` method. For instance:

```
shop.get(first_item, False)
```

Where the second argument is the default return in case the dictionary does not contain the item you are trying to access.

As Jon pointed out, you can also do something like this:

```
shop.get(first_item, [])
```

and iteration will stop if your dictionary doesn't contain that key.

Comment: Yup, and if you use `[]` as the default (instead of `False`) then the `for` loop will work as is or effectively be a no-op instead...

Comment: Slater Ive edited the post to clear up my requirements. Please help me on that. Thanks again.

Comment: @sunita You're calling `solver` but your function is called `solve_one_shop` - make sure your code is correct in your question as it's confusing what you're actually trying to run and what you're actually running...

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to access a key from the `dict` (here `shop`), which is not present. Hence the error. Check if that key `first_item` is present in your `dict`. You would not get this error (updated answer).

```
...
if first_item in shop:
    for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:
        ...
```

or use `try: except:`

```
   ...
    try:
        for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:
    except KeyError: 
        print 'ERROR: key not found!'
    ...
```

Comment: `has_key` has been deprecated for a *long* time (and has gone in Python 3). Use `if first_item in dict:` instead.

Comment: Or, even more pythonically, just try to retrieve it and `except` the `KeyError`, so that you don't hash your input twice.